# Google visualization: Stack columns. Issues with HTML custom tooltips

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

All my questions/problems are related to this Codepen where I developed a stacked column bar chart. Code bellow.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLIuB

**Issue 1 :**
I might have found a bug on custom tooltips. As you can see, for small groups (the ones where the there is not enoght space to put the annotation) the custom tooltip is not applied. Is there a way to solve it ?

**Issue 2:**
I don't understand why the HTML tooltip isn't enabled even if I followed the documentation. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content?hl=fr

**Issue 3:**
As you can see, it's absolutly impossible to click on the tooltip action because the tooltip is too far. Is there something to fix it ?

**Question:**
I will need to hide/show series by clicking on the legend. Is there something not documented to do it ? I found this way http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6gz2Q/ but it's a bit ugly.

**Advices appreciated :**
I take any advice to simply the google chart related code. Specially for formatting because it's seems that we have to format interger to get (X,XXX.X values format) even if the language is set to *en*. Am I right ?
Don't worry about the javascritp syntax, it will be rewritten when I will integrate it in my application. This is just a mock.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], language: "en"});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

//Input data
var data = [
    ['API Category', 'Social', 'Music', 'File Sharing', 'Storage', 'Weather'],
    ['2011', 9000, 5300, 1200, 1600,  6000 ],
    ['2012', 1005, 3400, 2600,  3600,  4009 ],
    ['2013', 6009, 2700,  2200,  1000,  1500 ]
  ];
var aggregates = ["Category", "Year"];
var metrics = ["Url count"];

function drawChart() {
  var options = {
    width: 1000,
    height: 550,
    legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3, textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 16 } },
    isStacked: true,
    tooltip: { isHtml: true }
  };

  var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

  //Formatters
  var intergerFormatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    groupingSymbol: ",",
    fractionDigits: 0
  });
  for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++){
    intergerFormatter.format(dataTable, i);
  }

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
  var cols = [0];
  for(var i=1; i<data[0].length; i++){
      cols.push({
        sourceColumn: i,
        type: "number",
        label: data[0][i]
      });
      cols.push({ 
        calc: "stringify",
        sourceColumn: i,
        type: "string",
        role: "annotation"
      });
      cols.push({ 
        calc: createTooltip(i),
        /*(function(i) {
                return function(dataTable, row){
                  return "Url count" + dataTable.getValue(row, i)+"</b>";
              };
           })(i),*/
        type: "string",
        role: "tooltip",
        p: {html: true}
      });
  }
  view.setColumns(cols);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.setAction({
      id: 'increase',
      text: 'View details in explorer',
      action: function() {
        selection = chart.getSelection();
        //TODO
      }
    });

  chart.draw(view, options);

  function createTooltip(col){
    return function(dataTable, row){
      var html = "<div></div>";
      html += aggregates[0] + ": " + dataTable.getColumnLabel(col) + "\n";
      html += aggregates[1] + ": " + dataTable.getValue(row, 0) + "\n";
      html += metrics[0] + ": " + intergerFormatter.formatValue(dataTable.getValue(row, col)) + "\n";
      return html;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue 1 seems to be due to annotations. When I disabled them, all custom tooltips are rendered.

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: There is a codepen which is similar (maybe better :p). But if you really need a fiddle I will create one

Comment: Oh sorry, didnt see the codepen, thats fine too. Well, has @nicolas alreay answered it?

Comment: Well Andrew Gallant answered all questions on Google forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Andrew Gallant**'s answer [Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/m59fvWjfpLQ)

**1** does indeed appear to be a bug.

**2** is because you are specifying the calculated column's properties incorrectly.  The object key should be "properties" not "p":

```
cols.push({ 
    calc: createTooltip(i),
    type: "string",
    role: "tooltip",
    properties: {html: true}
});
```

Tooltip actions are incompatible with HTML tooltips, however, you can recreate them in the HTML itself.

**3**, you need to specify the tooltip.trigger option to either be "selection" or "both", and then click on the bars to select a data point.  The tooltip will stay in place when you mouse away from the bar, so you can click on things in the tooltip.

Showing/hiding series by clicking on the legend is not supported by the API; you have to use something like the hack that I wrote to accomplish it.  Yes, it is ugly, but it works.

There is no single standard for formatting numbers in any given locale (beyond what characters to use for grouping and what to use for the decimal separator), so the API defaults to no formatting.  "#,###.##" might be common in English-speaking locales, but it is no more standard than "####.##" is.  You don't have to handle the formatting in javascript, though; you can handle it server-side

**Advices**

```
function createTooltip(col){
    return function(dataTable, row){
        var html = "<div></div>"; // this will create an empty div at the start of your tooltip - is that what you want?
        html += aggregates[0] + ": " + dataTable.getColumnLabel(col) + "\n";
        html += aggregates[1] + ": " + dataTable.getValue(row, 0) + "\n";
        html += metrics[0] + ": " + dataTable.getFormattedValue(row, col) + "\n"; // don't need to use a formatter here
        return html;
    };
}
```